# How to create a pop-up with a Picker where the picker is immediately active and with a 'Skip' option?

Tags: codenameone

I have a couple of places in my UI where the user clicks an action and then I'd like to show a pop-up with (something like) a `Dialog` to invite him/her to add optional information, e.g. use a `Picker` to enter a date.

The idea is that this popup should be as little intrusive as possible and require as few clicks as possible, so I was thinking something like a `Dialog` with an explanation text and a `Picker` already activated so the user can directly swipe to the right date and push Done, and also a [Skip] button to directly close the Dialog without entering anything.

However, I've tried many different solutions and the picker (even in Light mode) appears outside the Dialog and I can't get the Dialog to close when clicking Done in the Picker.

Does anyone have a suggestion on how this could be achieved?

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot?
If I understood correctly you placed a picker in a dialog. That won't work well. Pickers are dialogs and triggering a dialog from a dialog is a recipe for problems...

Comment: Yes, I’d already guessed that placing the Picker in a Dialog probably wasn’t a workable, so I’m interested in any appproach which could help achieve what I’m after. Basically, I’d like something like a Dialog, with a title at the top, then some explanatory text, then an already ‘open’ Picker to directly select a date and press OK (Come to think of it, pressing Cancel on the Picker could probably replace the need for a Skip button). Anyway, any other UI element that can be shown somewhere on top of the current screen would also be fine, it doesn’t have to be Dialog.

Comment: Maybe `InteractionDialog` will work better for your needs although I'm not sure as I don't fully understand what you're trying to accomplish. In general dialogs in Codename One should be relatively simple. See this: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/picking-dialog-type.html

Comment: Thanks Shai, And yet it was perfectly clear in my mind what I meant :-) I wanted a modal dialog. I finally found a way to implement it, in my answer here

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I finally implemented it, using the non-public components used by the Spinners (so the class must be placed in com.codename1.ui.spinner). I also noticed an issue in DateSpinner3D which sets the time of day randomly (to the time of activation), which means it may alter a Date even if not edited, but I'll do a PR for that.

I've only implemented support for the Picker elements I currently use.

So not fully reusable/generic solution, but hopefully it can help show how it can be done if anyone runs into the same need.

I've added a screenshot (only test colors): [![enter image description here][1]][1]

```
package com.codename1.ui.spinner;

import com.codename1.components.SpanLabel;
import com.codename1.components.Switch;
import com.codename1.io.Log;
import com.codename1.ui.Button;
import com.codename1.ui.Command;
import com.codename1.ui.Container;
import com.codename1.ui.Dialog;
import com.codename1.ui.Display;
import com.codename1.ui.layouts.BorderLayout;
import com.codename1.ui.layouts.BoxLayout;
import com.parse4cn1.operation.SetFieldOperation;
import java.util.Date;

public class PickerDialog {

    Dialog dlg;
    Command doneCmd;
    int type;
    DateTimeSpinner3D dateTimeSpinner;
    DateSpinner3D dateSpinner;
    DurationSpinner3D durationSpinner3D;

    public static String DONE_BUTTON_TEXT = "Done";
    public static String CANCEL_BUTTON_TEXT = "Cancel";

    public PickerDialog(String title, String text, Object value, String cancelText, String doneText, int type) {
        this.type = type;

        dlg = new Dialog();
        dlg.setDialogUIID("PickerDialog");
        dlg.setTitle(title);
        dlg.setLayout(BorderLayout.center());

        Container cont = new Container(BoxLayout.y());
        SpanLabel textSpanLabel = new SpanLabel(text);
        textSpanLabel.setTextUIID("PickerDialogText");
        cont.add(textSpanLabel);
        switch (this.type) {
            case Display.PICKER_TYPE_DATE_AND_TIME:
                dateTimeSpinner = new DateTimeSpinner3D();
                dateTimeSpinner.setValue(value);
                cont.add(dateTimeSpinner);
                break;
            case Display.PICKER_TYPE_DATE:
                dateSpinner = new DateSpinner3D();
                dateSpinner.setValue(value);
                cont.add(dateSpinner);
                break;
            case Display.PICKER_TYPE_DURATION:
                durationSpinner3D = new DurationSpinner3D(DurationSpinner3D.FIELD_HOUR | DurationSpinner3D.FIELD_HOUR);
                durationSpinner3D.setValue(value);
                cont.add(durationSpinner3D);
                break;
        }

        doneCmd = Command.create(doneText, null, (e) -> {
            dlg.dispose();
        });
        Button doneButton = new Button(doneCmd);
        Container buttonBar;
        if (cancelText != null && !cancelText.isEmpty()) {
            Button cancelButton = new Button(Command.create(cancelText, null, (e) -> {
                dlg.dispose();
            }));
            buttonBar = BorderLayout.centerEastWest(null, doneButton, cancelButton);
        } else {
            buttonBar = BorderLayout.centerEastWest(doneButton, null, null);
        }

        dlg.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, buttonBar);
        dlg.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, cont);

    }
    
        /**
     * return the value of the picker of the defined type (Date or
     *
     * @return
     */
    public Object show() {
        Command cmd = dlg.showDialog();
        if (cmd == doneCmd) {
            switch (type) {
                case Display.PICKER_TYPE_DATE_AND_TIME:
                    return dateTimeSpinner.getValue();
                case Display.PICKER_TYPE_DATE:
                    return dateSpinner.getValue();
                case Display.PICKER_TYPE_DURATION:
                    return durationSpinner3D.getValue();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ByvFK.png
```

Comment: This answer relies on internal non-public APIs. There's no guarantees they will be there in a future update and they can disappear without warning overnight.

Comment: Yes I thought that might be a risk. But hopefully at least it illustrates what I’m after. Do you see a better way of achieving it? Hope you can see the screenshot, seemed it only got inserted w a link at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: The screenshot didn't make it but I understand what you want. You don't want the picker button you want the spinner part embedded into your custom dialog. The reason this is problematic is that right now the component is a bit simplistic. On Android it should behave completely different so we need some more code that knows how to do all of that and that might require a major abstraction/refactoring to seamlessly switch these UI elements. Unfortunately there's no better solution at this time.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I guess I can continue embedding the spinner part for now (hoping that if you change it it will break already at compile level so I won’t need to test it with each build :-). If you change/remove it I guess I can fall back on using a Form to show a native spinner instead. The benefit of the Dialog is especially that it feels less intrusive and you can see the Form you’re in below so it reminds you of the context.